# Allow form to be edited once user clicks edit button

Tags: vb.net

I'm coding in Visual Basic. I have a file in Access that I am using as my Data Source. I have the form I am creating that is completely Read Only, so the user will not be able to edit any of the information.

My question is, I have created a button also on the form that I would like to put the form into edit mode when the user clicks the button, so the user will be able to make changes.

How would i go about doing that?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I have nothing, I am still trying to learn the syntax for Visual Basic and all that's available. So i was just wondering how someone with a lot more knowledge would do it? This is what i have.

Comment: Private Sub btnEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click
        '== Allow users to Edit the Orders/Customers

    End Sub

Comment: is there a command that i can use that says something like:

Comment: GroupBox1.ReadOnly = False  ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this level of simplicity is what you're looking for or not...

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    GroupBox1.Enable = False
End Sub

Private Sub btnEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click
    GroupBox1.Enable = True
End Sub
```

I *highly* recommend you read this thought for the future: 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

I'd also recommend watching tutorial videos and reading MSDN documentation on VB.NET.